# Combining Rails and jQuery, CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn how to combine jQuery and Rails. I have a table I've created with the accompanying CSS. I'd like to have the first  under every  to NOT have this border. I thought if I was able to select index[0] of the loop and apply the CSS with jQuery it would work but I wasn't sure how to go about this. Would I disable the css for .details-row or would I add on another class that had a border-top: transparent?

Any explanations or resources would be great, thank you.

- HTML

  ```
  <table>
    <% details.each do |details| %>
      <tr class='details-row'>
        <td class='detail-title col-md-6 js-text-productSpec'><%= specification.name %></td>
        <td class='detail-description col-md-6'><%= specification.description %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  ```
- CSS

  ```
  .details-row {
    border-top: solid 1px #dedede;
    td { 
      padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
  }
  ```

I'd like the table to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain " I'd like to have the first under every to NOT have this border"?

Comment: Okay, I included an image now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* to allow to put border in tr*/
  .details-row {
    border-top: solid 1px #dedede;
    td { 
      padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
    &:first-child { border-top: none; }
  }
}
```

pure css version:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table .details-row { border-top: 1px solid #dedede; }
table .details-row:first-child {border-top: none; }
table .details-row td { padding: 5px 0 5px 0; }
```

Also try removing `col-md-6` from td class since I think it is from bootstrap and is used for something different

This is a test in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hj5jpk7/

Comment: I tried this as well as first child or adjacent css selectors, but it didnt work...I heard that I had to use some rails to override it?

Comment: Can you share an screenshot or image or mockup about what you want and want you have?

Comment: Thanks for that, I totally understand what you've done and tried it myself, but maybe it's because I'm doing it in rails syntax and not just pure HTML that it's not identifying the css that way? I'm not sure, but I have definitely tried it this way and it's still not working. =(

Comment: you rails code is fine (I mean the iterator), you can view the source code in the browser and should be pretty similar to the example in pure html. Maybe it is related to: a. sass or b. bootstrap. I've added a pure css version instead of sass to verify if that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery, you can use `$('tr:odd')` which selects every other `<tr>`'s. So if you want `.details-row` to only apply to the `[0]` if would have to be the `:even` selector. `$('tr:even')` to select it

Resources:

http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/